# Add content-disposition metadata when uploading to s3 using the cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers, aws-cli

Using the AWS CLI, how do I upload a file and specify a value for the `Content-Disposition` response header? Through the console, this header can be created by adding it as metadata, but a CLI command will allow this to be part of a CI pipeline.

Content-Disposition response header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aws cli command `cp` has an optional argument `--content-disposition` that makes this possible. `--content-dispostion` can either be set as `attachment` or `inline`.

```
aws s3 cp <src> <dest> --content-disposition attachment
```

This works for setting the metadata when it is uploaded, but if you later copy this file to a different path in s3, the metadata will not persist. To allow it to persist, you need to explicitly set this at upload time with the `--metadata-directive REPLACE` argument. The final command I use is:

```
aws s3 cp <src> <dest> --metadata-directive REPLACE --content-disposition attachment
```

aws s3 cp documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html